# Python request to API gives SSL error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am working with `Python2.7` and I need to access a certain API (Nuagen): https://nuagenetworks.github.io/vsd-api-documentation/usage.html

In the documentation, they say the following:

> Getting the API key.
>   To obtain and API key, the first step is to make a /me API call. This API call returns information about the account being used.

```
    GET /me HTTP/1.1
    X-Nuage-Organization: my company
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: $AUTHORIZATION_STRING
```

> The authorization string for the /me API MUST be formatted like the following:

```
    $AUTHORIZATION_STRING = Basic base64($LOGIN:$PASSWORD)
```

So I try to build my requests in the folowing way;

```
import requests

url = 'https://an.ip.add.ress:8443/nuage/api/v4_0/me'
user = 'myuser'
passw = 'mypass'
cps = 'myorganization'

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic d29jdTpjdXdv",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Nuage-Organization": "csp",
}


response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, passw), headers=headers)
# Also tried with:
# response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

However, I'm always getting this error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)
```

Any idea on how to access this API with Python requests? Or any other way?

Comment: Does the server have a valid certificate?

Comment: I really don't know. Is there any way I could find out? But I can access the server via web browser and browse through its pages.

Comment: Use `curl`, `wget`, `openssl s_client`, your browser...

Comment: Yes, I can access it both via `curl` and via the web browser.

Comment: Then please try this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification